# Is it legal for me to use Visual Studio Community for learning?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Legally speaking, is it OK for me to use Visual Studio Community (2019) to learn C#? Microsoft's website seems to say that it's free to use for individual to create their own free and paid apps, but is it okay for me to use features of the IDE itself (i.e: something like intellisense) to learn about the various features of C#? So if I start using intellisense to tell me about the various functions and variables available in the "Console" class and I start experimenting with the various classes and variables to see and learn how they work, this is a perfectly legal thing to do correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking for legal advice from strangers on internet.

Comment: Maybe I should have posted on law.stackexchange.com instead? My bad for posting it here

Comment: Jacob - I don't think it would be appropriate on Law either as to properly answer such question you need legal advice which is not what that site for - I'd recommend you to doublecheck yourself so as I'm just occasionally visit that site mostly for entertainment value. If you just looking for casual way how license may be interpreted - you have your answer here, but that's in no way a legal advice and not much better than asking your dog/cat/teapot from legal point of view :)…

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  According to their website it's fine to use it for 'academic research'.  The only restricted use is large organizations with over 250 PCs or over $1,000,000 in annual revenue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Looking at the official license https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/mlt031819/

1 a. Individual License. If you are an individual working on your own applications, either to sell or for any other purpose, you may use the software to develop and test those applications.

Reading that you are ofcourse allowed to learn C# using Visual Studio Community

Also the website says: 
*Free, fully-featured IDE for students, open-source and individual developers*